# SQL Server Reporting Services installed with errors

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install SQL Server Reporting Services on my 64 bit laptop.

However all other software packages has installed successfully but only RS tool has not been installing. Here I am posting the error log this installation has generated. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052377
  Exit facility code:            1212
  Exit error code:               1639
  Exit message:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Start time:                    2015-04-09 23:21:10
  End time:                      2015-04-09 23:25:55
  Requested action:              Install
  Log with failure:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150409_232028\sql_rs_Cpu64_1.log
  Exception help link:           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.6000.34

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  MEDDI
  Machine processor count:       4
  OS version:                    Future Windows Version
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  Sql Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER         Database Engine Services                 1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER         SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER         Full-Text Search                         1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSAS10_50.MSSQLSERVER          Analysis Services                        1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2                                                       Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2                                                       Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2                                                       Client Tools Connectivity                1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2                                                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2                                                       Client Tools SDK                         1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2                                                       Integration Services                     1033                 Developer Edition    10.53.6000.34   No        

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008 R2
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2008 R2
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  SPLevel:                       1
  Installation location:         D:\first\Microsoft  SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          DEVELOPER

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      False
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASDOMAINGROUP:                 <empty>
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150409_232028\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CUSOURCE:                      
  ENABLERANU:                    False
  ENU:                           True
  ERRORREPORTING:                False
  FARMACCOUNT:                   <empty>
  FARMADMINPORT:                 0
  FARMPASSWORD:                  *****
  FEATURES:                      RS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  HELP:                          False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PASSPHRASE:                    *****
  PCUSOURCE:                     
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  ROLE:                          <empty>
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 FilesOnlyMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  False
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150409_232028\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Reporting Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Failed: see details below
  MSI error code:                0x1639
  MSI log file location:         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150409_232028\sql_rs_Cpu64_1.log
  MSI error description:         
  Configuration status:          Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150409_232028\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Thanks!

update

### `20150409_232028\sql_rs_Cpu64_1.log` File

```
=== Verbose logging started: 4/9/2015  23:25:47  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.9200.00  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2\x64\setup100.exe ===
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:022]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:022]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:022]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: D:\first\Microsoft  SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition\x64\setup\sql_rs.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:022]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:022]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:494]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:494]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:504]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (C4:58) [23:25:47:539]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction D:\first\Microsoft  SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition\x64\setup\sql_rs.msi
MSI (s) (C4:58) [23:25:47:539]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (C4:9C) [23:25:47:549]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (C4:9C) [23:25:47:549]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:9C) [23:25:47:549]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: D:\first\Microsoft  SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition\x64\setup\sql_rs.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (C4:9C) [23:25:47:554]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:9C) [23:25:47:554]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:9C) [23:25:47:649]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:9C) [23:25:47:649]: Specified instance {2453DBC8-ACC4-4711-BD03-0C15353AA3D8} via transform :InstID01.mst;:InstName01.mst is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.
MSI (s) (C4:9C) [23:25:47:649]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
MSI (s) (C4:58) [23:25:47:654]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:58) [23:25:47:654]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:58) [23:25:47:654]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (C4:58) [23:25:47:654]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (C4:58) [23:25:47:654]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (C4:58) [23:25:47:654]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:659]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (C0:80) [23:25:47:664]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
=== Verbose logging stopped: 4/9/2015  23:25:47 ===
```

Comment: I'd check out the `Log with failure: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150409_232028\sql_rs_Cpu64_1.log` and `Exception help link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.6000.34` it so helpfully provided you with.

Comment: Hi @ceejayoz   can i post that log in update section of my question?

Comment: @ceejayoz   I have updated my post with log file requested. please visit my post again. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a pretty clear error message in there. `InstName01.mst is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.`

Comment: actually i am a newbie in these issues, could you please explain a bit about this message. -if i need to uninstall and re-install ..?!?!

Comment: @ceejayoz is this link http://gemanjyothisqlserver.blogspot.in/2012/11/sql2008r2-installation-error-installer.html a possible solution to this kind of error. Please correct me if I am wrong. thanks!

Comment: @marc_s thank you so much boss for the edit

Comment: @ceejayoz ... i have tried all the options given above and have searched over search engine as well. but there is no benefit. 
I am still *unable* to install Reporting services on my machine.

Comment: Hello Admin, 

I have installed sql server 2014 successfully. I would like to request you to close this question please  as I was unable to resolve the errors I encountered.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at [sqlauthority](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/12/31/sql-server-installation-failure-specified-instance-via-transform-is-already-installed-msinewinstance-requires-a-new-instance-that-is-not-installed/)

Run `wmic` to get a list of installed SQL components

```
WMIC PRODUCT Where "Caption like '%SQL%'" GET Caption, IdentifyingNumber
```

Use `msiexec` to remove them:

```
Msiexec /X {GUID}
```

If an uninstall fails search the registry for the GUID (2453DBC8-ACC4-4711-BD03-0C15353AA3D8 in your case) and delete all keys.